# Differential equation - Solve for y

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 4xy^\frac12$$

I did

$$y^{-\frac12}\ dy = 4x\ dx$$
thus root $$y = 4x^2 + 2c$$
but the answer is $(x^2+c)^2$.

Help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Could you edit your question to include [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)? I would, but I can't tell exactly what 4x x root y is supposed to be

Comment: Sorry is dy/dx = 4xy^1/2

Comment: You have $\frac{d}{dx}~y^{1/2}=\frac12 y^{-1/2} \frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{d}{dx}~x^2=2 x$. Maybe it will help you see where your error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

You correctly separated this equation, but you need to add integral signs to both sides and then integrate them

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=4xy^{\frac 12} \implies \int y^{-\frac 12}\ dy =\int 4x\ dx$$

Can you do this?

Comment: That gives me,  1/2 y ^0.5 = 2x^2 + C

Comment: Not quite, remember when you integrate a polynomial you *divide* by the new power, so $y^{-\frac12}\to 2y^\frac 12$

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved the question from that one hint.

Comment: You're welcome. As an added point, you gave $y=4x^2+2c$ as your original answer. Don't forget that $c$ is arbitrary (as you are integrating indefinitely) so you can just replace $2c$ with $c$.